# How can I change the colors of GNOME Terminal each time it starts?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome

I heard about a script which will change the colors of GNOME Terminal each time it starts. I can't remember where I saw this...

Comment: You want different, random colors each time?

Comment: Well not random. It was more like predefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen the script you mention. But I think it is possible to create such a script.

Gnome Terminal [picks up the background colour from the profile in use](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-prefs.html.en#gnome-terminal-prefs-colors), so any change will impact the background colour of all terminals using the same profile.

That said, the configuration key is stored in */apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color*, where *Default* is the currently used profile.

It can be set thus:

> gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color" --type string "#E376DDDDFFFF"

So, I'm guessing that one can write a script to clone the *Default* profile on the fly, change it's *background_color*, invoke ***gnome-terminal*** with this profile, and delete the profile before exiting.  You'll also need a database of good foreground/background color combinations for this script to use.

---

**Update:** Here is a script to do what is discussed above. It does not generate a random background color, that you'll have to generate using some list.

```
#!/bin/bash 

PROFILE_NAME=${RANDOM}_p_${RANDOM}
TMP_DIR=/tmp
DEFAULT_PROFILE=Default
PROFILE_EXPORT_FILE=${TMP_DIR}/${PROFILE_NAME}.xml

#replace with program to generate a random background color
BACKGROUND_COLOR="#0000AA000"

# dump the "Default" profile, replace with new random profile name
gconftool-2 --dump /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/${DEFAULT_PROFILE} > ${PROFILE_EXPORT_FILE}
sed -i "s/${DEFAULT_PROFILE}/${PROFILE_NAME}/g" ${PROFILE_EXPORT_FILE}

# load the new random profile, change the background color
gconftool-2 --load ${PROFILE_EXPORT_FILE}
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/${PROFILE_NAME}/background_color" --type string "${BACKGROUND_COLOR}"

# add the new random profile to list of profiles
PROFILE_LIST=`gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/global/profile_list`
NEW_PROFILE_LIST=`echo $PROFILE_LIST | sed "s/]/,${PROFILE_NAME}]/g"`
gconftool-2 --set  /apps/gnome-terminal/global/profile_list --type list --list-type string "$NEW_PROFILE_LIST"
# start gnome-terminal with new random profile, such that the script blocks till terminal is closed.
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=${PROFILE_NAME} --disable-factory

# cleanup: remove the new random profile, and remove it from list of profiles
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/${PROFILE_NAME}
PROFILE_LIST=`gconftool-2 --all-dirs /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles | sed "s/ \/apps\/gnome-terminal\/profiles\///" | sed -n -e 'H;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;}'`
gconftool-2 --set  /apps/gnome-terminal/global/profile_list --type list --list-type string '['"${PROFILE_LIST}"']'
```