# Can I have my terminal background change based on hostname?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, gnome-terminal

I'd like to have my terminal background color change based on hostname. My reasoning for this is mainly to have and extra way to remind myself what server I am on, so I don't do something stupid.

Is there someway I can have it use the standard aubergine background if I am on my local machine, then change red if I ssh into a production web server, or other hosts that I could specify?

Comment: One idea, script the change to the environmental variable that handles the terminal settings. Make a script for each place you typically ssh to and include the change to the settings in that script, here is a guide that can help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/ - this way you can just run a script that will not only connect for you, but will customize the terminal for that particular session.

Comment: There's the same question on the ubuntu site: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13705/automatically-change-terminal-colors-on-remote-connection Mind, I don't blame you, I did not find it at first either :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use ssh/config's localcommand option to run a command whenever an alias is used.  I use

```
host hostname
    user myusername
    localcommand xtermcontrol --bg '#abc'
```

This depends on xtermcontrol and your term being xterm.  Presumably there are other apps for other terms.

The only problem with this approach is that it happens when you call ssh.  There's nothing to undo the color change.  I've done it by wrapping a function around ssh, but that has its drawbacks too.

```
function ssh() {
  FG=$(xtermcontrol --get-fg)
  BG=$(xtermcontrol --get-bg)
  $(which ssh) "$@"
  xtermcontrol --fg="$FG"
  xtermcontrol --bg="$BG"
}
```

Comment: I'm using AWS Linux2 and the xtermcontrol command doesn't exist.  I tried installing vai `sudo yum install xtermcontrol` but it was not found.  I like the idea of this solution.

Answer (score 8):

It does not seem that there is any functionality in `gnome-terminal` to [add a new tab to an existing window](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-terminal/+bug/117333) from the command-line. But there are a few options to accomplish what you want.

## Per Command Profiles

Create a new `gnome-terminal` profile for each host you will SSH into.  If you only have a few hosts that you regularly connect to, this might be the simplest. Each profile can have a different title, foreground color, background color, custom command and other settings defined. Then you can use `File -> Open Tab` to open a new tab with the selected profile.

## Reuseable Profile

Create a new `gnome-terminal` profile that will be used to open a new window each time you want to connect to a different SSH host (based on this [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13705/automatically-change-terminal-colors-on-remote-connection/21340#21340) that [Stefano](https://superuser.com/users/50125/stefano) pointed out). This would work good if you connect to many different hosts frequently. This will not allow you to distinguish between different `gnome-terminal` windows where you are connected to different hosts solely on the background/foreground colors, but you will have a different title per window.

1. Create a new `gnome-terminal` profile (`File -> New Profile`) based on the `Default` profile and call it "RemoteHost" (note, no spaces in "RemoteHost" to make commands easier).
2. Under the `Title and Command` tab, change:

   1. `Initial title:` to "Remote Host"
   2. `When terminal commands set their own titles:` to `Replace initial title`
3. Under the `Colors` tab, change:

   1. Uncheck `Use colors from system theme`
   2. `Build-in schemes:` to `Custom`
   3. `Text color:` and `Background color:` to colors of your choosing. Keep in mind that some commands (like `ls`) use colors for their output and you don't want to pick colors that will make it difficult to read the output.
4. Click on the `Close` button to save your new profile.
5. Now you can open a new `gnome-terminal` window for each remote SSH host using the command `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=RemoteHost -t "Some Remote SSH Host" -x ssh user@somehost`. The `-t` option sets the `gnome-terminal` window title and the `-x` option executes the rest of the command line in the terminal. You could even make an `alias` to shorten total keystrokes.

## Command-Line

I found [this blog entry](http://gleamynode.net/articles/2236/) with the following script that uses the `xdotool` and `wmctrl` commands (they weren't installed by default on Ubuntu, so you might need to install them first) to use the `gnome-terminal` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> keyboard shortcut to open a new tab in the current `gnome-terminal` window. It could be modified to open a new tab with a specific profile and execute some command for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Path: /usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal
if [ "x$*" != "x" ]; then
  /usr/bin/gnome-terminal "$@"
else
  pgrep -u "$USER" gnome-terminal | grep -qv "$$"
  if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
    WID=`xdotool search --class "gnome-terminal" | head -1`
    xdotool windowfocus $WID
    xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
    wmctrl -i -a $WID
  else
    /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
  fi
fi
```

## Other

You could get creative and try some other things.

This [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/41826/how-can-i-change-the-colors-of-gnome-terminal-each-time-it-starts/42179#42179) basically uses a bit of "script-fu" acrobats to create a temporary `gnome-terminal` profile that is used to open a new window. It may be modified for your use.

You could probably use this [StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932084/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-10) and more "script-fu" acrobats to dynamically change the `gnome-terminal` title whenever you SSH to a remote host. It would not be as prominent as background/foreground color changes, but it would be better than a standard `Terminal` title all the time.

Answer (score 6):

This will work in Gnome, IF you're willing to use a new gnome-terminal window for each ssh session.

1. Create a new profile (with different background colour) called "Remote"
2. Insert the following into `.bash_aliases`, or `.bashrc`

   ```
   ### add to .bash_aliases, for differentiating between local and remote hosts 
   sshhelper() {
      gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Remote -x bash -c "ssh $1";
   }
   alias sshc=sshhelper
   ```

Now `sshc remote-machine` opens a *new* gnome-terminal session with the "Remote" profile. this will differentiate between local and remote profiles.

To accommodate multiple profiles/hosts, create multiple profiles and place something like this in `.bash_aliases` instead :

```
### add to .bash_aliases, for differentiating between multiple remote hosts
sshhelper() {
    HOST=`echo $1 | cut -d'@' -f2`

    case $HOST in
        Production )  PROFILE="Red" ;;
        Test )        PROFILE="Green" ;;
        # ... if you have more cases ...
        *)           PROFILE="Default" ;;
    esac

    gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=$PROFILE -x bash -c "ssh $1";
}

# alias ssh=sshhelper    # this will "override" the ssh command, but may break other stuff!
alias sshc=sshhelper
```

Now `sshc Production` will open a new session window using the "Red" profile, `sshc Test` will open a new session window using the "Green" profile, and other hosts will use the "Default" Profile.

Comment: What does "create multiple profiles" mean. Can you include how to do that (preferable in code). Also what is "Production" meant to be. If I normally `ssh` with `user@host` should it be this?

Answer (score 3):

Gathering all information from stack*** sites here is the simplest solution I've found for mint mate + mate terminal (same as for gnome).

1. In mate terminal define second profile, with different background.
2. Check if default keys work Alt+PageDown / Alt+PageUp should change the profile, and the background as well.
3. `sudo apt get install xdotool`

Now you can modify /etc/ssh/ssh_config, so that it can change the profile after each ssh session is established:

```
Host *
  PermitLocalCommand yes
  LocalCommand xdotool key Alt+Page_Down
```

Now, after each ssh connection is established in the terminal, the profile will be changed and you will never put unwanted sql update to production database again :)

However, there's no easy solution to achieve back to default profile after the ssh connection is closed. But this looks enough for me, and I didn't dig for more info.