# How to change terminal colors when connecting to SSH hosts

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnome, colors

So you want to change terminal colors and reset them back on exit?

It's possible thanks to `.ssh/config`, `alias`, and `setterm`

Comment: I know, we have tons of such questions, but I just did not found any simple as my current version. Also to those, who can expand my answer with details, pls expand it. Then after more detailed version we can accept it.

Answer (score 30):

- `.bash_aliases`:

  ```bash
  function ssh_alias() {
    ssh "$@";
    setterm -default -clear rest;
    # If `-clear rest` gives error `setterm: argument error: 'rest'`, try `-clear reset` instead 
  }

  alias ssh=ssh_alias
  ```
- `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

  ```bash
  # Ensure this line exists:
    PermitLocalCommand yes
  ```
- `.ssh/config`:

  ```bash
  Host your.production.host
    User root
    LocalCommand setterm -term linux -back red -fore white -clear rest
  ```

In Bash, you can now:

```bash
some command

# all in default colors:
  ssh your.production.host

# colors changed:
# ....

exit
# colors changed back! yeea!
```

---

### Alternative to `setterm`:

If you are using `gnome-terminal`, or another `xterm`, and are frustrated by the limited color choices of `setterm`, and/or your `setterm` changes are being overridden by color codes in your command prompt [`$PS1`], instead of `setterm` you may wish to use `xtermcontrol`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/691290).

- For example, `xtermcontrol --bg '#600'` will make the terminal background a dark red, although you may need to install `xtermcontrol` before using it *(e.g. `sudo apt install xtermcontrol` on Debian-based systems)*

Comment: When i login I get the following error: `setterm: argument error: 'rest'`
Any idea why?

Comment: `man setterm`, search there `--clear`. In mine version it exists.

Comment: Can anyone add description of the changes done

Comment: Unfortunately this recipe breaks rsync. I am getting these messages when runnung rsync: `protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [Receiver=3.1.3]
` It is not due to the wrong setterm argument

Comment: Since you're using a shell wrapper anyway, it might make more sense to keep all `setterm` use in it, otherwise you have half the logic in the SSH config, the other in the wrapper. If you need per-host tuning, probably easier to differentiate via wrappers, too.

Comment: So these changes are made locally? It also means I cannot use a different color for different remote systems?

Comment: works fine until remote system changes colors via `ls`, `grep,` or any other color changing command.  :(

Comment: Any idea why LocalCommand won't find aliases?
I added `alias set-to-production-color-scheme="xtermcontrol --bg '#470202'"` to `.bash_aliases`, but when setting `LocalCommand set-to-production-color-scheme` it says "/bin/bash: line 1: set-to-production-color-scheme: command not found". When calling the alias directly, it works just fine.

Answer (score 7):

*(Read gaRex's [response](https://superuser.com/a/603910/529800) first)*

`setterm` has changed the arguments in recent versions: *(more info: `man setterm`)*

- `.bash_aliases`:

  ```bash
  function ssh_alias() {
    ssh $@;
    setterm --default --clear all;
  }

  alias ssh=ssh_alias
  ```

  You can still use `--clear rest` and reload `.bash_aliases` via `exec bash`
- `.ssh/config`:

  ```bash
  Host myproject.pro
    HostName myproject.com
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myproject
    LocalCommand setterm --term linux --background white --foreground black --clear all
  ```

Comment: This is a 3 year old question and your answer is similar to the one already answered

Comment: yep... I only wanted to add more info. Could be a response to gaRex's response.

Comment: yep i am with and clearly understand you want to help and we want folks like you

Comment: click on "improve this answer" in my initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this when connecting to my own computers. What I did was as simple as adding this snippet to my `.bash_profile` (which is in my dotfiles, so it ends up in most of my computers anyway):

```bsh
[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] && echo -e "\033]11;#336699\a"
```

You can change the `336699` for any hex color you want.

Comment: this solution don't let me copy files using `scp`

Comment: @vik that's because you're not checking if it's an interactive session (`[[ $- == *i* ]]`)

Answer (score 1):

I follow a similar approach to Enrico's, changing the background/foreground of the terminal, then connecting to the server, and changing back the original color when disconnecting from the servers, with no admin permission needed, only requiring a few lines added to `.bash_aliases`:

```bash
alias background_local='printf "\e]11;#333333\e\\"'
alias background_server='printf "\e]11;#336699\e\\"'
alias goto_server='background_server; ssh server ; background_local"
```

- If you wish, you can mix and match, changing also the foreground color with the command:

  ```bash
  alias foreground_server='printf "\e]10;#fff2af\e\\"'
  ```

I assumed you have a working `.ssh/config` file, so `ssh server` connects to your server; for completeness, in `.ssh/config` you may want to have:

```bash
Host server
  HostName address.to.your.server
  User yourusername
```

Answer (score 0):

On Apple Mac/OSX, `setterm` is not available, but you can use `osascript` with a little shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

DEFAULT_SCHEME=Basic
SCHEME=${1:-$DEFAULT_SCHEME}
SAFE_SCHEME=\"${SCHEME//\"/}\"  # sanitize user input

/usr/bin/osascript <<EOF
tell application "Terminal"
  set current settings of window 1 to settings set $SAFE_SCHEME
end tell
EOF
```

- This takes a single argument corresponding to one of the colour schemes `terminal` knows about *(e.g. Ocean)* and may be invoked in place of `setterm` in the above answers, remembering to also add it to `~/.bash_aliases` so the terminal reverts to the original colour scheme when when you exit the `ssh` session

The default `bash` profile on OSX does not source `.bash_aliases`, so you may need to add something like this to `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  source ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

- For additional information on how to change the terminal colours in OSX, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89609/in-a-bash-script-how-do-i-sanitize-user-input).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Yakuake, but the same steps work with Konsole, so this answer is "KDE/Konsole" specific.

I wanted to change terminal colors when connected to important servers, and switch it back when ssh session was closed. Based on [gaRex's answer](https://superuser.com/a/603910/1742162) I did the following:

1. Enabled `PermitLocalCommand yes` in `~/.ssh/config`
2. Added `LocalCommand konsoleprofile ColorScheme=RedOnBlack;TabColor=#FF0000` to the `Host` directive for production servers
3. Modified `ssh` to be a function in my `~/.zshrc`, by inserting `ssh() { /usr/bin/ssh "$@" ; konsoleprofile ColorScheme=Breeze}` there

`/usr/bin/konsoleprofile` is a neat script, self described as

> A command-line tool to change the current tab's profile options.

So before every ssh connection, my current console will change it's color scheme to `RedOnBlack`, and tab color will be red too (this works only in Konsole so far, can't find a way to change yakuake tab color)

And then, after SSH is closed, color scheme will be reset to my default - Breeze.