# How to reset on Ubuntu the terminal text color back to defaul once a SSH connection is closed

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, terminal, colors

**System: Ubuntu 20.04**

**My goal:** change terminal text color when I connect to SSH host and reset the terminal text color once the SSH connection is closed.

**Status:** I managed to change the text color when I establish the SSH connection (--> [How to change terminal colors when connecting to SSH hosts](https://superuser.com/questions/603909/how-to-change-terminal-colors-when-connecting-to-ssh-hosts))

`.bash_profile`

```
[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] && echo -e  '\033]10;#ff0000\007'
```

**Problem:** The terminal text color is not reset once I close the SSH connection.

Can this be done by editing `.bash_profile`? How can this be done not following the approach used in the mentioned article?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to put

```
[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] && echo -e  '\033]10;#ffffff\007'
```

into

```
.bash_profile
```