# Invoking a local command on every successful connect when using ssh multiplexing?

Tags: command-line, ssh, multiplexing

I'd like to automatically run a command every time I successfully connect to a remote host via ssh.

I can do this for the first connection to each host using the `PermitLocalCommand yes` and `LocalCommand ~/bin/ssh-notify-me` entries in my `~/.ssh/config`, similar to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/347512/can-i-have-my-terminal-background-change-based-on-hostname/691290#691290) but I am also using a quite aggressive ssh multiplexing configuration (approximately the following):

```
Host *
PermitLocalCommand yes
ServerAliveCountMax 2
ServerAliveInterval 5
ControlPath ~/.ssh/mux/%r@%h:%p
ControlMaster auto
ControlPersist 1h
```

With this setup, the LocalCommand is only executed for the first connection before a control master/mux socket exists. Thereafter, I connect, but the command does not run.

Is there any way (without disabling muxing) to ensure that LocalCommand or some equivalent occurs for every new interactive session opened?

Wrapping `ssh` binary either in a shell function or script seems like it wouldn't work because it can't know if the connect was successful until after it's completed.

Comment: When you say "every new session", does that just mean interactive sessions (where you get a command line prompt on the remote server)? Or does it include non-interactive sessions? How about scp sessions? sftp sessions? Does this command produce output to the terminal?

Comment: @Kenster: Sorry, yes. I meant every interactive session (so normal `ssh foo`, and `ssh foo -t <cmd>`, but not scp/anything else that doesn't get a pty allocated. Edited question to clarify.

Comment: `automatically run a command every time I successfully connect` – And this is exactly what happens. `man 5 ssh_config` says about `ControlMaster`: `Enables the sharing of multiple sessions over a single network connection`. So there is only one connection. The master `ssh` process creates it (connects), any consecutive `ssh` uses it. I understand what you want to achieve; my point is you're using the word "connection" where "session" is what you mean.